# Bootstrap 5 Modal Showing In The Wrong Location

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I really dont know why but for some reason the Bootstrap 5 Modal is showing inside the sidebar menu instead of the main area.

Other Bootstrap 5 components, including Toasts are also showing inside the sidebar instead of the main area.

How this can be fixed? And What is causing the issue?

Test example below:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="body-pd" class="body-pd">

    <div class="l-navbar show" id="nav-bar">
        <nav class="nav">
            <div> <a href="/" class="nav_logo"><span class="nav_logo-name">Test</span> </a>
                <div class="nav_list">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <span class="nav_name">home</span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  </body>

<style>
    :root {
      --header-height: 3rem;
      --nav-width: 68px;
      --first-color: #979797;
      --first-color-light: #3300FF;
      --white-color: #F7F6FB;
      --normal-font-size: 1rem;
      --z-fixed: 100;
    }
    
    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
      margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      font-family: var(--body-font);
      font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
      transition: .5s;
    }
    .l-navbar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: -30%;
      width: var(--nav-width);
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: var(--first-color);
      padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
      transition: .5s;
      z-index: var(--z-fixed)
    }
    
    .nav {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      overflow: hidden
    }
    
    .nav_logo,
    .nav_link {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
      align-items: center;
      column-gap: 1rem;
      padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem
    }
    
    .nav_logo-name {
      color: var(--white-color);
      font-weight: 700
    }
    
    .nav_link {
      position: relative;
      color: var(--first-color-light);
      margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
      transition: .3s
    }
    
    .nav_icon {
      font-size: 1.25rem
    }
    
    .show {
      left: 0
    }
    
    .body-pd {
      padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 1rem)
    }
    
    .active {
      color: var(--white-color)
    }
    
    .active::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 2px;
      height: 32px;
      background-color: var(--white-color)
    }
    
    .height-100 {
      height: 100vh
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      body {
        margin: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem) 0 0 0;
        padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
      }
    
      .header {
        height: calc(var(--header-height) + 0.2rem);
        padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
      }
      .l-navbar {
        left: 0;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0
      }
    
      .show {
        width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px)
      }
    
      .body-pd {
        padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 170px)
      }
    }
        </style>
    
</html>
```

Already tried to move stuff around and make some small changes, but no luck, I'm missing something for sure.

Comment: renaming your class called `show` to anything else fixes this issue. I don't know what the reason is exactly, but I'm guessing bootstrap uses the `.show` class and its causing a weird interaction with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see.

The cause is you defined styles of `.show` class.
The show class is added automatically when the modal is shown.

So, you have to modify the class name `.show`, like this:

.show => // navbar-show(modified class name)

Attach example code. hope it helps

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="body-pd" class="body-pd">

    <div class="l-navbar navbar-show" id="nav-bar">
        <nav class="nav">
            <div> <a href="/" class="nav_logo"><span class="nav_logo-name">Test</span> </a>
                <div class="nav_list">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <span class="nav_name">home</span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  </body>

<style>
    :root {
      --header-height: 3rem;
      --nav-width: 68px;
      --first-color: #979797;
      --first-color-light: #3300FF;
      --white-color: #F7F6FB;
      --normal-font-size: 1rem;
      --z-fixed: 100;
    }
    
    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
      margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      font-family: var(--body-font);
      font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
      transition: .5s;
    }
    .l-navbar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: -30%;
      width: var(--nav-width);
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: var(--first-color);
      padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
      transition: .5s;
      z-index: var(--z-fixed)
    }
    
    .nav {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      overflow: hidden
    }
    
    .nav_logo,
    .nav_link {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
      align-items: center;
      column-gap: 1rem;
      padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem
    }
    
    .nav_logo-name {
      color: var(--white-color);
      font-weight: 700
    }
    
    .nav_link {
      position: relative;
      color: var(--first-color-light);
      margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
      transition: .3s
    }
    
    .nav_icon {
      font-size: 1.25rem
    }
    
    .navbar-show {
      left: 0
    }
    
    .body-pd {
      padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 1rem)
    }
    
    .active {
      color: var(--white-color)
    }
    
    .active::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 2px;
      height: 32px;
      background-color: var(--white-color)
    }
    
    .height-100 {
      height: 100vh
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      body {
        margin: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem) 0 0 0;
        padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
      }
    
      .header {
        height: calc(var(--header-height) + 0.2rem);
        padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
      }
      .l-navbar {
        left: 0;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0
      }
    
      .navbar-show {
        width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px)
      }
    
      .body-pd {
        padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 170px)
      }
    }
        </style>
    
</html>
```